# FreeCad broken package

Tags: dependencies

After updating to ubuntu 20.10 from 20.04 which remove freecad when trying too reinstall Freecad I get

```
    building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help resolve the situation:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libfreecad-python3-0.18 : Depends: libboost-regex1.71.0-icu66 but it is not installable
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
$ apt-cache policy freecad libfreecad-python3-0.18
 Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:0.18.4+dfsg2~202007252144~ubuntu20.10.1
  Version table:
     2:0.18.4+dfsg2~202007252144~ubuntu20.10.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu groovy/main i386 Packages
     0.18.4+dfsg2-5build1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe i386 Packages
libfreecad-python3-0.18:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:0.18.4+dfsg2~202007252144~ubuntu20.10.1
  Version table:
     2:0.18.4+dfsg2~202007252144~ubuntu20.10.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
     0.18.4+dfsg2-5build1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: That sounds like a broken package didn't get removed.  You should file a bug, chances are FreeCAD has dependencies that no longer work (so it should be removed).

Comment: On fresh 20.10 FreeCAD installs normally. Please add the output of `apt-cache policy freecad libfreecad-python3-0.18` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1294459/edit).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove [problematic PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Efreecad-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/freecad-stable) with commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable
```

and use FreeCAD from the [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/freecad) by

```
sudo apt-get install freecad
```

Comment: Thank I have remove the PPA will try a fresh install of Freecad

Comment: Hi, by doing that you will install and use the official freecad packaged for/by Ubuntu. By using PPA package source you'll install and use a more recent stable version. Choose what you want ...